# Checking existing table rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Can somebody tell me what I've done wrong inside my coding? I am trying to match the user login name and password with the one inside the database. If got row and matched then user will be able to login into the system but it seems like my system can only read the first row of my data table (inside database).

Here is my coding that I currently use.

```
Private Sub CheckLogin()
        Dim lCnn As New SqlConnection
        Dim lCmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim lRd As SqlDataReader
        Dim lsCmd As String

        If TextBoxLogin.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter your Username.")
            Try
                TextBoxLogin.Focus()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        ElseIf TextBoxPass.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter your Password.")
            Try
                TextBoxPass.Focus()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Else
            lCnn.ConnectionString = GetConnString()
            lCnn.Open()
            lCmd.Connection = lCnn
            lsCmd = "SELECT * FROM UserInfo..UserInfo "
            lsCmd &= " INNER JOIN UserInfo..UserAccess ON UserLogin = UA_UserLogin "
            lsCmd &= " WHERE (UserLogin = " & SQLQuote(Trim(TextBoxLogin.Text)) & " AND UserPassword = " & SQLQuote(Trim(TextBoxPass.Text))
            lsCmd &= " AND UserActive = 1"
            lsCmd &= " AND UA_AICode = 'MENU')"
            lCmd.CommandText = lsCmd

            lRd = lCmd.ExecuteReader()

            If lRd.HasRows Then
                lRd.Read()
                lbLoginSuccess = True

                    gsLoginID = Trim(TextBoxLogin.Text)
                    gsUserPass = Trim(TextBoxPass.Text)
                    Me.Close()
                Else
                    lnCurRetry += 1
                    Alert("Wrong Username or Password.")
                End If
            lRd.Close()
            lCnn.Close()
        End If

        If Not lbLoginSuccess Then
            If lnCurRetry >= 3 Then
                Me.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not really bad, but can be better if utilize that sintax:

```
     Using LCnn As New SqlConnection

      LCnn.ConnectionString = GetConnString()
      Try

        LCnn.Open()
        Using LCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM UserInfo " & _
                                     "INNER JOIN UserAccess ON UserLogin = UA_UserLogin " & _
                                     "WHERE (UserLogin = '" & TextBoxLogin.Text.trim & "' " & _
                                     "AND UserPassword = '" & TextBoxPass.Text.Trim & "' " & _
                                     "AND UserActive = 1 AND UA_AICode = 'MENU')", LCnn)


            Dim LRdr As SqlDataReader

            Try
                LRdr = SQL_Cmd.ExecuteReader
                If Not SQL_Rdr.HasRows Then
                    msgbox("Empty Results...")
                else
                    <your code>
                endif

             catch ex as Exception
                    msgbox("Error: " & ex.message)
             end try

        end using    ' Lcmd

     catch exConn as Exception
           msgbox("Error: " & exConn.message)
     end try


 end using     ' LCnn
```

Remember: the Using/End Using syntax can help you to manage resources. End Using always close and dispose resources.

Good luck

Comment: The result is still the same. My coding should be able to let the user (any user refer to the database) with correct username and password to login into the system right?

Comment: If the Query functions inside SQL-Management and NOT functions outside (via TCP/IP for instance), the problem may be related to SQL is not accepting external connections. Are you sure other simplest queries run into SQL from external programs?

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. My coding is actually correct. I forgot that I set the access only for admin. That's why it only read 1 row. I'm so sorry. Is it possible to remove this? So that people don't get confuse

Comment: No. don´t remove since this sample can be usefull to other guys, even if in a different scenario. I just ask you to vote in my answer, since it allows me to collect points - and the code is correct anyway.  Thank you and good luck!

Comment: It seems like I am not able to vote yet since my reputation is too low. By the way thank you so much :)

Comment: :)  No problem at all. Your words are enough to make me happy. Kindest regards.